A number count of players in a gamemode
I'm creating a scoreboard for my event server for crystal pvp, In it show show the amount of players in the gamemode survival as the rest would be in spectator. Can someone please help me, I'll send a screenshot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you want the command block answer, or the Java (programming language) answer?

You can 'output' the number of people in a given gamemode by /executeing /scoreboard on all players that are [gamemode={gamemode}].
Replace {gamemode} with survival, creative, adventure, spectator, !survival, !creative, !adventure or !spectator
First, create your objective and some holders.
/scoreboard objectives add alive dummy {"text": "Gamemode"}
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar alive
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomNameVisible:true,CustomName:Survival}
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomNameVisible:true,CustomName:Creative}
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomNameVisible:true,CustomName:Spectator}

Problem now, is if you /scoreboard players set @e alive 0, you'll get a bunch of UUIDs... Something like this:

Next, you have to rename your entities' scoreboard display. While players default to their names, entities are their UUIDs. You can get the UUID of your armor stands by just:
/say @e

And hovering over the name of your armor stand, like this:

You may want to use Target Selectors to narrow down the @entities you are targeting...
For the case of this example, we'll assume these three UUIDs, you'll have a different set for however many/what you create.
5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 (Survival)
02bf57fc-c901-4b9f-b55c-7804418aec88 (Creative)
f8b9d112-2fd1-4c2f-98b0-33c6ced1f424 (Spectator)

So first, add them all to your scoreboard...
/scoreboard players add {uuid} alive 0

/scoreboard players add5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 alive 0
/scoreboard players add02bf57fc-c901-4b9f-b55c-7804418aec88 alive 0
/scoreboard players addf8b9d112-2fd1-4c2f-98b0-33c6ced1f424 alive 0

Repeat that for every armor stand/condition you would like tracked.
Next, change the armor stand's UUID to something more pleasant... Like "Players Alive".
/scoreboard players display name {uuid} alive {"text": "Players Alive"}

/scoreboard players display name 5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 alive {"text": "Players Alive"}
/scoreboard players display name 02bf57fc-c901-4b9f-b55c-7804418aec88 alive {"text": "Creative"}
/scoreboard players display name f8b9d112-2fd1-4c2f-98b0-33c6ced1f424 alive {"text": "Spectators"}

Next, make everyone increment a /scoreboard, once per player.
/scoreboard players set {uuid} alive 0
/execute as @a[gamemode={gamemode}] run scoreboard players add {uuid} alive 1

/scoreboard players set 5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 alive 0
/scoreboard players set 02bf57fc-c901-4b9f-b55c-7804418aec88 alive 0
/scoreboard players set f8b9d112-2fd1-4c2f-98b0-33c6ced1f424 alive 0
/execute as @a[gamemode=survival] run scoreboard players add 5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 alive 1
/execute as @a[gamemode=creative] run scoreboard players add 02bf57fc-c901-4b9f-b55c-7804418aec88 alive 1
/execute as @a[gamemode=spectator] run scoreboard players add f8b9d112-2fd1-4c2f-98b0-33c6ced1f424 alive 1

Now run this every frame (aka. put it in a command block chain).
For more information, read up on:

Target Selectors
/scoreboard
This YouTube video which spells it out in Plain English
JSON Text Format or this tool

If you want the display to be hidden; like in the screenshot, or be in a particular order:

Set a different scoreboard with the score being the order and set as the main /scoreboard objectives setdisplay {location} otherScore displayed scoreboard instead.
Using the same /scoreboard players display ... command, you can chain scores and text, for example: /scoreboard players display name 5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9 survival [{"text": "Players Alive: "},{"score": {"name": "5bfa7107-3f5e-466b-ac37-cbf6512a83a9","objective": "alive"}}]
Hide the numbers from the scoreboard with /scoreboard objectives modify otherScore numberformat blank (this can be done on the individal entity level as well).

